# PostMessage goes wrong if I press CTRL or SHIFT

Tags: autohotkey

```
HoldLeftClick(600, 400, 4000, WindowName) ; ( coord x, coord y, delay in ms, window name where to hold left click)

HoldLeftClick(x, y, delay, Window) {
    PostMessage, 0x201, , ((y<<16)^x), , %Window% ;WM_LBUTTONDOWN
    sleep, delay
    PostMessage, 0x202, , ((y<<16)^x), , %Window% ;WM_LBUTTONUP
}
```

I have this code and I am using it to hold left click on a specified window.

My problem is that if I press CTRL key or SHIFT key, bad things happens in that window, same thing happens if the window is in background and I have other window that is active!

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: what are "bad things"? And I guess it should be `sleep, %delay%`